# How to access resource of another dll in a project

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, reference, resourcedictionary

I have added Resource Dictionary of a referenced dll in my project. It is an ImageDictionary. Now I want to set source of my image as one of the images in the dictionary. How do I do it? this is how it used to be accessed in the original project.

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource LoadDrawingImage}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your window properties, you need to declare this:

```
xmlns:Image="clr-namespace:[namespace];assembly=[nameofdll]"
```

and then use like this:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource Image:LoadDrawingImage}"/>
```

Comment: If it worked please mark my answer as accepted :)

Comment: This won't work, because adding a XAML namespace prefix to a resource key will not magically make the resource from a referenced assembly available in the current project. Actually, adding a namespace prefix to a resource key is invalid XAML syntax. This post should be deleted.

Comment: No it's not, because I have a profissional project and sometime we use it like this example.

Comment: You are certainly confusing things here. `Image:LoadDrawingImage` is not a valid resource key.

Comment: That's the example using the data provided in the question. "Image" is the name I gave to the declaration, It can be different.
"LoadDrawingImage" is the source of the image that the use gave as an example that he wanted to use.

Comment: Sure, I can see what you are trying to say. It's still wrong. Try the following. Create a library project with some ResourceDictionary with an entry with a certain key. Create a WPF application project, add a reference to the library, and try to access the external resource by its key via StaticResource  as you are showing it here.